# Skikit learn train_test_split return weird values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Skikit Learn's train_test_split function it returns all the arrays fine apart from X_test which returns weird values not from the data set This is the code below.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

heart_data = np.genfromtxt("cleveland.txt", delimiter=",")
hd_y = heart_data[:,13]
X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(heart_data,hd_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print(X_train,y_train)
print(X_test,y_test)
```

> Returns this - (Shortened the arrays, as they were to long)

```
 #X_train
[[58.  1.  3. ...  0.  7.  0.]
 [50.  0.  3. ...  0.  3.  0.]
 [70.  1.  4. ...  0.  7.  4.]
 ...
 [61.  1.  4. ...  1.  7.  2.]
 [35.  1.  2. ...  0.  3.  0.]
 [49.  1.  3. ...  3.  7.  3.]] 
 #y_train
[0. 0. 4. 2. 1. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 3. 1. 1. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 4.
 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 2. 1. 2. 1. 3. 2. 0. 1. 0. 1. 2. 2. 2. 1. 3. 0. 1
 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 3. 2. 0. 3.]
 #X_test
[[5.30e+01 1.00e+00 4.00e+00 1.40e+02 2.03e+02 1.00e+00 2.00e+00 1.55e+02
  1.00e+00 3.10e+00 3.00e+00 0.00e+00 7.00e+00 1.00e+00]
 [4.00e+01 1.00e+00 4.00e+00 1.52e+02 2.23e+02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 1.81e+02
  0.00e+00 0.00e+00 1.00e+00 0.00e+00 7.00e+00 1.00e+00]
 [5.10e+01 0.00e+00 4.00e+00 1.30e+02 3.05e+02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 1.42e+02
  1.00e+00 1.20e+00 2.00e+00 0.00e+00 7.00e+00 2.00e+00]] 
 #y_test
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 3. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 2. 4. 3. 0. 1. 0. 0.
 0. 1. 1. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 3. 0. 0. 3. 0. 4. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 4. 3. 2. 0. 0.
 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 3. 3. 0. 0. 2.]
```

Comment: By weird values not from the data set, do you mean the scientific notation in `X_test`? I think you may want to explicitly convert all your data into float32 format by `heart_data = np.genfromtxt("cleveland.txt", delimiter=",").astype(np.float32)` , before you use the `train_test_split`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but it still is producing the same output

Comment: What do you mean by weird values? 5.30e+01 is 53 for example, what is weird about that?

Comment: Completely unrelated to your issue, but you left the `y` vector (idx 13) in your `X`, so beware of leakage.

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments, I forgot to say i've i have fixed the problem and now my neural network is running smoothly.